# Prove a set is not convex

Tags: geometry

I came up with a question to prove a set $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2>8\}$ is not convex.
I have tried the definition of convex set but it does not seems obvious to me.. the book suggests drawing it to decide but I would like to know how to work it out by calculation.
Thanks

Comment: But once you draw it, you can see how the calculation should go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counter example:

Consider $A=(-100,0)$ and $B=(+100,0)$ in the set. However, $C=(0,0)$ on the line $l1$ connecting $A$ to $B$ does not belong to the set.

Always remember [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Convex_polygon_illustration1.png/220px-Convex_polygon_illustration1.png).

Comment: To fill in a logical detail in the original question, here's how one uses the definition of a convex set. That definition is: **for every** pair of points $A,B$ in the set, the line segment $\overline{AB}$ is in the set. The negation of the definition is: **there exists** a pair of points $A,B$ in the set such that the line segment $\overline{AB}$ is not in the set. That's how you know to look for a counterexample, which is what this answer gives.